# TS/JS How can I find an index of objects nested property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, indexing, indexof

I'm having an array of such dummy objects of type 'Human':

```
    {
      id: '3',
      details: {
        hair: 'blonde',
        age: 20
     }
```

and I would like to get the index of the first and last person of the same age. I've had high hopes for

```
first = arr.map(element => element.details.age).findIndex(20);
```

as well as

```
last = arr.lastIndexOf((element) => element.details.age === 20);
```

however, both of them produce the same error:

```
Argument of type '(element: any) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Human'.
  Type '(element: any) => boolean' is missing the following properties from type 'Human': id, details
```

I'm either in need of help on how to make those array functions work or a different solution that will give me the same result.

Comment: Can you share more of your code? From the look of those lines it looks correct, does the error say which line has the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array.findIndex and Array.lastIndexOf work differently.

findIndex takes a lambda that returns boolean, while lastindexof takes the object to search for.

To solve your problem you can call .reverse on your array and then use findIndex again.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for either

```
first = arr.map(element => element.details.age).indexOf(20);
//                                              ^^^^^^^
last = arr.map(element => element.details.age).lastIndexOf(20);
//                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or

```
first = arr.findIndex(element => element.details.age === 20);
//          ^^^^^^^^^
```

It seems you had them mixed up.